# Trim characters from content instead of words - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've been looking for a solution for quite some time. But can't find it somehow.

What I need is a function that shows a specific amount of characters from the content, instead of a specific number of words. Because words can be longer than other words and I want to keep the styling from the post preview equal.

Now I'm still using trim words:

```
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 15 ); ?></p>
```

Does anyone know how I can trim characters from the content of a post instead of the amount of words?

Thank you in advance!

Update:

Here is my complete posts section:

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category__in' => array(2, 3),
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
      );
    ?>
    <?php $query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

      <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <div class="post">
          <?php $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
          <div class="post-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumb;?>');"></div>
          <div class="post-prev">
            <?php
            foreach (get_the_category() as $category){
              echo "<span>";
              echo $category->name;
              echo "</span>";
            } ?>
            <h2>
              <?php
                $thetitle = $post->post_title;
                $getlength = strlen($thetitle);
                $thelength = 20;
                echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
                if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "..";
              ?>
            </h2>
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 15 ); ?></p>
            <span class="btn">Lees verder</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); else : ?>
      <p><?php _e("Geen content gevonden.."); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to have exact the amount of characters (potentially cropping words) or do you want _max_ x amount of characters with only complete words? Also, you probably want to strip any HTML from the contents first, or you could get a string with invalid/broken HTML markup.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I want to have an exact amount of characters that breaks words with a "...". What you say about breaking the HTML markup, yeah I've experienced that. The answer below does just that.

Comment: Search for setting excerpt length WP. There are different options, it depends on your theme.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've done that multiple times, but that leads me to code for the excerpt function in Wordpress. Not trimming the amount of characters that's in the content from that post. I don't want to fill in the excerpt aside from the content.

Comment: Then this should do: `echo substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()), 0, 15);`. That will give you a string, without any broken (or any) HTML, that's exactly 15 characters. If you want to keep any HTML but fix it, it would require something different and much more complicated.

Comment: Is the problem that you would use `the_excerpt’ except that it returns a specific number of words instead of characters?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's exactly what I needed. Works perfect! Thank you. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark that as the solution? Again, thank you.

Comment: @ThomasTromp - Added it as an answer with a bit more explanation around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly 15 characters without any HTML in the string, you can do it in steps:

First get the string and remove the HTML using [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$content = strip_tags(get_the_content());
```

Then you grab the 15 first characters from the now HTML-less string using [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr):

```
echo substr($content, 0, 15);
```

That would do it.

You can also do it as a one-liner:

```
echo substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()), 0, 15);
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid cutting words, I am using the following custom function:

```
function theme_truncate( $string, $length = 100, $append = '&hellip;' ) {
$string = trim( $string );

if ( strlen( $string ) > $length ) {
    $string = wordwrap( $string, $length );
    $string = explode( "\n", $string, 2 );
    $string = $string[0] . $append;
}

return $string;}
```

It is using PHP [wordwrap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) and [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to achieve the goal.

You can, later on, call this function like this:

```
echo esc_html( theme_truncate( get_the_content(), 15 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,15); ?></p>
```

If the output from the method `get_the_content()` is a string, then you can use `substr()` method. The above example outputs 15 characters starting from index 0

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, however this seems to break the HTML..

Answer (score 0):

[wp_html_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_html_excerpt/) is the function you are looking for:

```
<p><?php echo wp_html_excerpt( get_the_content(), 15, '...' ); ?></p>
```

It will strip all HTML tags and truncate the content up to 15 characters, adding `...` at the end.